# Prove that a given recursive sequence converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the following recursively defined sequence converges and find its limit.

\[a_1 = 1,   a_{n+1} = 1- \frac{1}{4a_n}\]

I understand that this sequence is decreasing, however, I struggle to find a way to prove that it converges. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just show that it is bounded.  Done.

Comment: Can you show that it is a bounded sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the following:

$1)$ Your sequence is decreasing and bounded below.

$2)$ $$\lim _{n\to \infty}a_n= \lim _{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}$$

You can take it from here.